# Finding Linearly independent Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I stumbled upon a problem which is as below

Take the subset of 2 x 3 matrices consisting of matrices with first row entries adding up to zero and the second column sum equal to double the third column sum. Find four linearly independent matrices in the above subset.

I'm not sure how to proceed upon this problem, Do I make a guess work like try to randomly fix 3 matrices and find the 4th matrix. Also it would help me to solve a similar kind of problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Start by picking $1$ non-zero matrix in the set.  Then see how you can play with it and still remain in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&-a-b\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}$ be such a matrix. This matrix already satisfies the row condition. For it to satisfy the column condition, we want
$$b+e=2(-a-b+f) \implies \color{blue}{e=-2a-3b+2f}.$$
Thus
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&-a-b\\d&-2a-3b+2f&f\end{bmatrix}.$$
We can express this as 
$$a\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&-2&0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-1\\0&-3&0\end{bmatrix}+d\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}+f\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&2&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
These four matrices are linearly independent and satisfy the requirements of the subset.

Comment: Yes I understood the logic behind this problem thank you so much